# Rails -- Find with 3 conditions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, find, conditional-statements

Hey, I got a find condition that is a bit lengthy and I'd like make it lengthier.

SO far

```
:conditions =>  ["name LIKE ? OR description LIKE ?", "%#{params[:search_keyword]}%",
        "%#{params[:search_keyword]}%"]
```

Where it's searching the model for if the attribute :name or :description is like a param from a text box.  Now I'd also like to add to make sure the entries found are current.  I already have

```
:conditions => ["start_date between ? and ? ", Date.today, @yearstime ]
```

Where @yearstime is @yearstime = Date.today + 365.days  so essentially everything thing in the model from the present date to a year from now

I'd like to combine both conditions but am unsure of the syntax.  I tried to put it all together.

```
:conditions =>  ["name LIKE ? OR description LIKE ? AND start_date between ? and ?",
 "%#{params[:search_keyword]}%", "%#{params[:search_keyword]}%", Date.today, @yearstime ]
```

but it still isn't calculating for the date parameter....Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's probably an order of operators issue. Try

```
:conditions =>  ["(name LIKE ? OR description LIKE ?) AND (start_date between ? and ?)",
 "%#{params[:search_keyword]}%", "%#{params[:search_keyword]}%", Date.today, @yearstime ]
```

The `AND` operator has a higher precedence than `OR`

Reference:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/operator-precedence.html

Answer (score 0):

Is start_date a date, or a date_time. Might be a casting issue from one to the other.